# Restarting the airflow scheduler

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I'm trying to get airflow working to better orchestrate an etl process. When I make changes to a dag in my dags folder, I often have to restart the scheduler with

```
airflow scheduler
```

before the changes are visible in the UI. I would like to run the scheduler as a daemon process with

```
airflow scheduler -D
```

but we I try to do so, I get a message saying

```
[2018-10-17 14:13:54,769] {jobs.py:580} ERROR - 
Cannot use more than 1 thread when using sqlite. Setting max_threads to 1
```

I think this error pops up because the scheduler is already running as a daemon. However, when I try to find out where the scheduler is being run with

```
lsof -i
```

I don't get any results.

**Question:** Why am I not able to restart the scheduler with `airflow scheduler -D`. Why does the scheduler restart with `airflow webserver`? How do I successfully kill the process that is preventing me to run `airflow scheduler -D`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run `ps aux | grep airflow` and check if `airflow webserver` or `airflow scheduler` processes are running. If they are kill them and rerun using `airflow scheduler -D`

Comment: It works! I used: 
>> ps aux | grep airflow 
>> kill -9 PID_NUMBER

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear out the airflow-scheduler.pid file at $AIRFLOW_HOME. The stale pid file from the daemon will prevent you to start another scheduler process.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that has ever been a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just restart your webserver, the dag changes gets reflected in UI. No need to restart scheduler for the same.
Applicable for 1.8 and 1.10.3. Cant comment for latest 1.10.10.