# Cannot use sqlite with the LocalExecutor [AIrflow]

Tags: docker, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to restart the airflow scheduler using the following command

```
airflow scheduler
```

I am using docker. I went inside my docker image for airflow and opened the CLI for my airflow image. That is where I used this command.

It throws an exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin import LoggingMixin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .decorators import apply_defaults as _apply_defaults
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/decorators.py", line 36, in <module>
    from airflow import settings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 37, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf, AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG  # NOQA F401
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 731, in <module>
    conf.read(AIRFLOW_CONFIG)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 421, in read
    self._validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 213, in _validate
    self._validate_config_dependencies()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 247, in _validate_config_dependencies
    self.get('core', 'executor')))
airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite with the LocalExecutor
```

I am looking for any way to restart the airflow scheduler.

Comment: When I open the CLI it looks like this sh-4.4$

Comment: I think you cannot use sqlite with LocalExecutor.  https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/817
you can do either 1) use SequentialExecutor with sqlite or 2) use different DB with LocalExecutor.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected.

Since sqlite doesn’t support multiple connections it can only be used with `SequentialExecutor`. This is also explained in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/sequential.html#executor-sequentialexecutor).

If you want to use `LocalExecutor` please set MySQL or PostgreSQL as backend.

Comment: My goal here is to restart the airflow scheduler. How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854824/restarting-the-airflow-scheduler